# How to do git log -L with jGit?

Tags: git, jgit

I want to find the commit history of particular lines using jGit. This can be done in CLI using git log -L. How to do this in jGit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [API](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.1.3.201810200350-r/apidocs/index.html) lists explicitly all available flags, and it seems unfortunately, **there is no implementation for the line range option, `-L`** (at this time). `git log` is much more flexible than the `jgit` API.

The best you could do is to use the `.addPath('/path/to/file')` method before the `.call()` to narrow things down, and then calling `DiffCommand` between each pair of returned commits on the file using the `setPathFilter` - Finally you have to parse the result yourself to see if your specific line was touched.

Comment: So, is there any way to get the commit history of a line in jGit?

Comment: @ArshakAnj I am afraid you would have to do things yourself. `addPath` will allow you to focus on a file, but then you would actually have to parse yourself if your line was changed in each commit, for example by using `DiffCommand` and parsing it.

Comment: I will add that to the answer.